# html table using rowspan colspan

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to create a table that looks as follows ..

[image]

```css
table, td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan='6' colspan='6'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td rowspan='4'>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In the my code, are the empty rows causing it to mis-print the table ?
Can you tell why browsers are rendering it incorrectly ? Or flaw in logic ?

Comment: It looks correct, could you please explain a little more of what the problem is? Oh wait a sec... ok it looks like it isn't printing the 6x6 correctly, right?

Comment: And also that 4 x 1 looks either of 1 x 1 (if you run the embedded snippet) or like a 3 x 1 (if you run in chrome) ! (take dimensions as row x col please)

Comment: Ok, review my answer and see if that's it.

Comment: @Ankur looks like there is no issue here.. if the issue is how it look like, that is only because there is no content I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your css on cell dimensions.

Here is what you could do.

```css
table,
td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  text-align: center;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
}
td {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan='6' colspan='6'>6X6</td>
    <td rowspan='4'>4X1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: basically, when the height of the table is not known, rowspans and colspans cant calculate the width and height they need. so setting the height and width of you each cell should tell how much each cell would need and then caclculate the rowspans and colspan values correct. Your markup isnt changed much. but the css needs to be modified for the td width and heights.

Comment: :) providing dimensions in px can be done to the <div>'s also .. and thus those are the choice to be made instead of <table> .. and yep no shuffling around is going on in the answer as per 'change' .. it's just that the provided dimensions are doing the trick ..

Comment: Yea exactly thats correct @Ankur. no changes to the markup, updated my comments

Comment: Even I m not an advocator on using table for layouts, I prefer other markup elements

Answer (score 0):

in this case, I suggest you use `div` float layout instead of a `table` layout. Add 11 div blocks with `float:left` style will be much easier to solve

Comment: yes that option is of course there .. but just wondering why it would not render properly .. that's all